# Altering one python list in dictionary of lists alters all lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two separate python lists acting as one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969609/two-separate-python-lists-acting-as-one)

This code creates a dictionary of lists, the keys being in `usens`. The lists are full of `0`s

```
usens = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114,
         115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 302, 303, 306, 307, 308, 370, 371, 500,
         501, 1000, 1010, 1020, 1100, 1200, 1201, 1202, 2000, 2001, 2002
         ]
empty = [[0]*length]*len(usens)
data = dict(zip(usens, empty))
pprint.pprint(data, indent=5)

data[0][0] += 1
pprint.pprint(data, indent=5)
```

The first pretty print returns the expected (blurb removed):

```
{0: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 1: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 3: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 4: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 5: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 .....
 2001: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 2002: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

I then do this: `data[0][0] += 1`, expecting the first list (of index `0`) to begin with `1`, but nothing else to change.

However, all the lists have been modified:

```
{0: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 2: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 3: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 4: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 .....
 2001: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 2002: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

**Why, and how can I make it so only one list is modified?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two separate python lists acting as one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969609/two-separate-python-lists-acting-as-one) and also see  [Yet another list aliasing conundrum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997559),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`empty = [[0]*length]*len(usens)` will create `len(usens)` copies of the same list, which is different from `len(usens)` lists with the same content.

Try `empty = [[0]*length for i in range(len(usens))]`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `*` creates copies; for `[0]` it's fine, because it's copying an immutable scalar; but the outer `*` creates copies of the same list (i.e., copies a reference). You could use something like:

```
empty = [0]*5
data = {n:list(empty) for n in usens}
```

(a dict comprehension) to create your list (if using Python 2.7+). Using `list` makes a copy.

Comment: Actually, using `*` *doesn't* create copies. It's the lack of copies that's the problem. You have numerous references to the same list, rather than the copies you thought you were getting.

Comment: Depends on how one uses the word "copy". It creates copies of the reference; not different references with copies of the value(s) (as a `copy.deepcopy` would). It'd probably be clearer if he said "multiple references" though.