# How can I set a cell in python matrix?

Tags: python, wxwidgets

that's my problem:

```
self.gameField = [
    ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
    ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
    ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
    ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
    ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
    ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
]
```

As you can see, I've created a matrix using list, I need to change a single element of a column selected by user, so I've tried with this code:

```
for z in self.gameField:
    if z[num] == "-":
        z[num] = "X"
        print "Done"
```

Where 'num' is an integer from 0 to 6 to indicate the sub-list. I want to select a colum, and set the lowest ' - ' available (like if there's gravity), so for example, if I select '0'

```
        ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
        ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
        ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
        ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
        ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
        ['X', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
```

But actually my program change the value of all the column

```
        ['X', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
        ['X', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
        ['X', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
        ['X', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
        ['X', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
        ['X', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
```

How can I fix it? Have you got any ideas to do that?

Comment: Create your 2d list using something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447882/python-2-7-creating-a-multidimensional-list. This should fix your referencing issue.

Comment: how are you initializing your matrix? because this could be a classic example of [multiple list references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969609/two-separate-python-lists-acting-as-one)

Comment: `for z in self.gameField` will iterate over every 'row' and set the 'cell' to `X` if it is `-` in the column referenced by `num`.

Comment: @RedShift,  a sublist is not changing so it cannot be a referencing issue

Comment: @Marco, you are changing all the first elements of each sublist so obviously they all look the same, `self.gameField [0][0]` would just get the first element of the first row, `self.gameField [5][0]`  would get the first element of the last row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting previous comments together:

Assuming your grid is created well (see possible issue with multiple sub-lists references - basically if you created your grid with something like `self.gameField = [[['_']*7]*6]`, which *seems* short and clean, it is actually bad in your case), you just need to break out of the `for` loop as soon as you place an `"X"` (otherwise you just keep filling the whole column!):

```
for z in self.gameField:
    if z[num] == "-":
        z[num] = "X"
        print "Done"
        break
```

Note that you might want to iterate your rows (your `for` loop) in reverse order so that gravity is downwards when you print your grid (or print your grid in reverse)...

Answer (score 0):

First of all defining `lists` in `lists`, you still need to seperate the `lists` with `,`. So the following.

```
[['-','-']['-', '-']]
```

Would become.

```
[['-','-'],['-', '-']]
```

Secondly instead of looping through the `lists`, you are able to access `list` indexes in this fashion.

```
gameField[3][3] = 'X'
```

This access has a runtime of 1, if considering the algorytmic factor, not relevant now. But scaling up could become a problem. Putting it all togheter i created the following running code.

```
gameField = [['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]

gameField[3][3] = 'X'

print(gameField)
```